# reading from tem-file, separating into header - data-blocks and normalizing columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-manipulation

Working on a project, where I need to read a TEM file, extract its content into two blocks (header + data), where the header is a dictionary.

Following I need to normalize the data e.g. [V/A]->[V/m^2] by the values of the dictionary. and save the normalized values into a DataFrame.

So far I haven't been able to find any snippet that helps me.

This is what I've been able to do so far:

```
fid_data='measurements.tem'
raw_columns=["f1","f2","f3","f4","f5","f6","f7","f8"]
raw=pd.read_csv(fid_data,names=raw_columns,sep='\\t',engine="python")
header=raw.iloc[:7,:]
data=raw.iloc[7:,:]
header.head()
sounding_properties={
'sounding_name':'foo',
'tx_loop':25.000,
'rx_loop':25.000,
'time-range':5,
'stacks':7,
'current':4.1
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm quite new to data-manipulation, so this may appear quite mundane to some of you, anyway I'm grateful for every piece of advice I can get.

Comment: That is no problem but you're still not really asking a question. You're just stating what you want to do and what you have done.

Comment: @Carl the question here is how to extract the file into two blocks, [data] starts at line 8 in the file, thus the header till 7.

Comment: and further how to normalize the data. The end result should be a TEM file in the same format, with additional columns done by calculations with functions